# Instantiate a task in ADA

Tags: task, ada, parameterized

I need to create a parameterized task in Ada, and the error I'm getting is:
discriminants must have a discrete or access type.

Here is my code:

```
task type FEP_Con(Port_Num :  Port_Name) is
  entry Start;
end FEP_Con;

type FEP_Con_acc is access FEP_Con;

task body FEP_Con is
  S_Port : Serial_Port;
  Buffer : Ada.Streams.Stream_Element_Array(1..1024);
  Last   : Ada.Streams.Stream_Element_Offset;
  Response_Str : Unbounded_String;
  --cPort : Port_Name := "";
begin
  accept Start;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though the type definition for "Port_Name" isn't provided, based on the discriminant name I presume it's a fixed-length string or Unbounded_String or somesuch. Neither of which are discrete or access types.

Discrete types are "either integer types or are defined by enumeration of their values (enumeration types)". [RM 3.2[3]](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-2.html#p3)

An [access type](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-10.html) is a "pointer" type.

So for your task discriminant you can use some integer-based type--that doesn't necessarily mean derived or subtyped from Integer, but just a counting integer type, e.g. `type Port_Name_IDs is range 1 .. 100;`

Or you can define your Port_Names as an enumeration, e.g.:

```
type Port_Name is (Haifa, Amsterdam, Long_Beach);
```

Or define an access type referencing your existing Port_Name type, e.g.:

```
type Port_Name_Ref is access Port_Name;
```

Comment: Or something like `task type FEP_Con (Port_Num : access constant Port_Name)`.

Comment: Thanks Marc and Simon, with enumeration it worked. Though I couldn't apply Simon's suggestion, as I couldn't pass the name of the port, to a type of 'access constant Port_Name'. (Port_Name is a type defined in GNAT.Serial_Communication)

Comment: You need to provide an access to the value. See https://www.dropbox.com/s/hun5qfs54g9pspv/test_discrims.adb (not to pollute the SO space with another answer!)